# What am I doing wrong in this query?

Tags: php, mysql

There are three tables,

- storing user details
- storing groups details
- storing user and group ids.

I need to check if a user is already a member of one group. I'm using this query to achieve that:

```
SELECT u.id, g.id 
FROM users u, groups g 
INNER JOIN user_groups ug 
ON ug.user_id = u.id AND ug.group_id = g.id 
WHERE ug.user_id = ? AND ug.group_id = ?
```

but this is throwing me an error:

```
Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in
```

I have checked if i have misspelled some word in my query and everything is okay.

EDIT:

Here is a function:

```
public function isUserMember($user_id, $group_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
            SELECT u.id, g.id from users u, groups g 
            INNER JOIN user_groups ug 
            ON ug.user_id = u.id AND ug.group_id = g.id 
            WHERE ug.user_id = ? AND ug.group_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $group_id); // here i'm getting an error
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num_rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        return $num_rows > 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the php code related to the query.

Comment: It's not the query, I guess you're not correctly preparing the statement..

Comment: We need the actual code, everything from establishing the database connection, to preparing / executing the query.

Comment: you can optimize your query like this      SELECT ug.id, g.id 
from  user_groups ug  
inner join  groups g 
on ug.group_id = g.id 
WHERE ug.user_id = ? AND ug.group_id = ?

Comment: Even when your current error isnt related to your query. This has a problem. You dont join `USERS` and `GROUPS`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Tables `users` and `user_groups` are joined, and tables `user_groups` and `groups` are joined. Thus, no need to directly join tables `users` and `groups`.

Comment: @Jocelyn   the table users and group are not joined .. this could be the problem

Comment: @Jocelyn Sorry but the correct `JOIN` need two `ON` should be  `FROM user_groups ug JOIN users u ON ug.user_id = u.id JOIN  groups g ON ug.group_id = g.id `

Answer (score 1):

Try following changes

removed unnecessary join with user table because if you have user_id and group_id you don't need to join it with user

```
SELECT ug.id, g.id 
from  user_groups ug  
inner join  groups g 
on ug.group_id = g.id 
WHERE ug.user_id = ? AND ug.group_id = ?
```

Comment: what are the changes you've made? **edit** your answer and add some context

Comment: Your suggestion will probably work, but Juan Carlos Oropeza query was also working for me. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your specific issue Error statement is:

> Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in

at:

> ```
> $stmt->bind_param("ii", $user_id, $group_id);
> ```

What this means is that there is no function `bind_param()` on boolean (true or false) , so this means your `$stmt` is a boolean, meaning the statement defining line has returned *`FALSE`*.

so:

> ```
> $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
>             SELECT u.id, g.id from users u, groups g 
>             INNER JOIN user_groups ug 
>             ON ug.user_id = u.id AND ug.group_id = g.id 
>             WHERE ug.user_id = ? AND ug.group_id = ?");
> ```

This is where the problem is. Others in comments have stated that your SQL query is incorrect, which would result in a boolean fail, however, *if* it is not your SQL query itself that is failing, then you would need to establish that the `$this->conn` value has been successfully generated and that it is a valid *object* entity.

Try to output an error log something like:

```
 if(!$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql)){
            $errorDump = '
            Error 1 '.date("r").' :
            ';
            $errorDump .= $this->conn->error;
            $errorDump .= "\n\nBacktrace:\n".print_r(debug_backtrace(),TRUE);
            $errorDump .= "
             SQL: ".$sql;
            error_log($errorDump);
            unset($errorDump);
            return false;
        }
    ....
   //carry on with the query as it's ok
```

The above is a bit *quick and dirty* but when your `$stmt` returns false this error report will tell you why. You can then use *that* error information to solve your Query or your PHP variable structure.

Comment: Your answer is well explained, but i have found out that my query was causing me this problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I have tried to show you how to find future errors and issues, you may have found your error this time but try and take in what I've stated here and you can solve your own errors in much less time when they happen again :-) @DusanDimitrijevic

Comment: Thanks @Martin for these tips :)